# CMake / CPack: location of third-party libraries in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, cpack

We're working on a multi-platform C++ GUI project. We have dependencies on some third-party libraries (e.g. `boost`, `fftw`, etc.) and these also get delivered and installed, so there's no need for our users to download extra components.

Right now, for the MacOS build, an app bundle is generated (`MyProject.app`). We're using the `PackageMaker` `CPack` Package Generator. All needed third-party dependencies get instaled under `MyProject.app/Contents/Frameworks`.

We recently completed a suite of command line tools that we'd like to include in our installer. So we'll be installing our bundle, `MyProject.app` along a folder, say, `Tools`, including our new command line utilities.

To make things more interesting, our application bundle is composed of some gui and core components, and we represent each component and our tools as different `CMake` projects (i.e., we use the following `CMake` commands: `project(gui_components)`, `project(core_components)` and `project(tools)`). Our tools depend on the core components, but not on the gui components.

Basically, what we'd like to have is the following folder structure:

```
<install folder>
  |
  |--MyProject.app
  |   |
  |   |--<all MacOS bundle needed folders/files>
  |
  |--Tools/
  |   |
  |   |--ToolA
  |   |--ToolB
  | 
  |--lib/
      |
      |--libboost_regex
      |--libfftw
      |--libgui_components
      |--libcore_components
```

How can I tell `CMake` / `CPack` to install third-party dependencies (in this example: `libboost_regex`and `libfftw`) in the `lib` folder? They are still being installed under `MyProject.app/Contents/Frameworks`. We've already managed to install own `libgui_components` and `libcore_components` in the `lib` folder.

Comment: Have you found a solution?